# Não Mostrar Valor Blank com DAX

Tags: if, powerbi, dax

Bom dia pessoal, estou tentando criar uma função no DAX que ao invés de mostrar o valor blank no meu dashboard, mostre o valor 0. Mas minha o power bi estão me retornando os seguinte erro:

**`

> The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be
>   converted to a scalar value

`**

Não estou conseguindo identificar o que está errado na expressão. 
Alguém poderia me ajudar a identificar o problema?

**Segue abaixo meu código DAX**

```
TotalGastosGlobo = VAR SOMA_GLOBO = FILTER(Gastos_Emissoras;Gastos_Emissoras[Emissora] = "Globo")
                    RETURN
                    IF(NOT(ISBLANK(SOMA_GLOBO));
                    SUMX(Gastos_Emissoras;Gastos_Emissoras[Total Geral - Governo Federal]);
                    0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui resolver o problema com a ajuda de uma colega aqui.

**Segue solução:**

```
GastosEmissoras = 
                   VAR SOMA = SUMx(Gastos_Emissoras;Gastos_Emissoras[Total Geral - Governo Federal])

                   RETURN
                     IF(ISBLANK(SOMA); 0; SOMA)
```